# Cookie message show only once per click / submit button accept

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help for cookies message popup. I want that message show only once per user CLICK accept. 
Here is code: https://jsfiddle.net/bz8ur3wu/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".cookie").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

```css
 .cookie{width:100%;padding:20px;background:rgb(231, 231, 231);bottom:0;left:0;position:fixed;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cookie">
    This website use cookies. 
    <button>accept</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Set a cookie when the button is clicked. Check for the existence of this cookie before deciding wether to  display the popup or not.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you please show this option in jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/bz8ur3wu/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a little script to include in every project.
It creates a cookie and check if exists or not so show or hide a div with id `#cookie-notice`

I think it's a good start. then you can personalize as you wish

```js
var myProj = myProj || {}
myProj.cookiePolicy = function (__M) {
    var cookiePolicy = document.querySelector('#cookie-notice'),
        acceptCookieBtn = cookiePolicy.querySelector('#cn-accept-cookie'),
        closeCookiePolicy = cookiePolicy.querySelector('a.close-button');

    closeCookiePolicy.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        acceptCookie();
    });

    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
        acceptCookie();
    });

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (ev) {
        acceptCookie();
    });

    acceptCookieBtn.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        acceptCookie();
    });

    if (document.cookie.indexOf('cookie_notice_accepted') === -1) {
        cookiePolicy.classList.add('show');
    }

    function acceptCookie() {
        if (document.cookie.indexOf('cookie_notice_accepted') === -1) {
            cookiePolicy.classList.add('show');
            // set cookie
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            document.cookie = 'cookie_notice_accepted=true' + ';expires=' + d.toGMTString();
        }

        if(cookiePolicy){
            cookiePolicy.parentNode.removeChild(cookiePolicy);
            cookiePolicy = null;
        }
    }
}(myProj);
```

Comment: Thank you Martino. Can you pleaseee show this option in jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/bz8ur3wu/1/  I'am trying but i'ts not working. :(

Answer (score 3):

As alternative solution I suggest `localstorage`. Look for a `cookieconsent` value and add a class to the `body` if you've found it; otherwise set the value when the user click the button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (!!localStorage.getItem("cookieconsent")) {
        document.body.classList.add("cookieconsent")
    } 
    else {
        $("button").click(function() {
            localStorage.setItem("cookieconsent", "ok")
            $(".cookie").fadeOut();
        });
    }
});
```

then in your CSS show the .cookie element only if user didn't accept before, that is, if the `body` has not the `.cookieconsent` class

```
.cookie { 
    display: none; }

body:not(.cookieconsent) .cookie {
    display: block;
}
```